# jquery.min.js & jquery-ui.min.js Vs jquery.* * .js file?

Tags: jquery

I am not very conversant with jQuery and want to know some basic things about jQuery's js files. 
**What is the basic difference in** `jquery min js & jquery js` ***file e.g. drag, drop, mouse, model etc..***
    Suppose i am working with jQuery Dialog Model,

- Downloaded from [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/download)
- js files saved in my web application 
  and include the js file as given below
- if i need to use drag & drop then
  again i need to include respective
  jquery js file

```
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
     ......... .......                   .......
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

Now i find another way to manage with just two files and do not need to include any separate js file for any other functionality e.g. drag, drop. I downloaded the two js files only

```
1. jquery.min.1.*.js  and   2. jquery-ui.min.1.*.js

<script src="ui/jquery.min.1.*.js"></script>

<script src="ui/jquery-ui.min.1.*.js"></script>
```

My Question is , Which one is correct & best way to deal the issue. BTW i feel comfort using `jquery min js` files. what do you say

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `min` versions are [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29). All non-essential characters are removed so the files are smaller and their download times shorter.

I'd recommend using the minified version, unless you're debugging jQuery itself (in that case, working with readable source code is more important than download speed).

Answer (score 2):

The min files have just been compressed and should be used in a production environment or any situation in which bandwidth is an issue.  The files without min can be used during development to view the source of the respective file, since they are not compressed or obfuscated the source is readable.